# How do I initailize abstract class protected field?

Tags: c#, field, abstract-class, protected

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Ant ant = new Ant();
        ant.description="small"; //This line goes wrong
    }
}
abstract class Pet
{
    protected string description;

}
class Ant: Pet
{
    protected int group;
        
}
```

How do I initialize description?Besides, description must in protected level.

Comment: You can add a ctor to class `Pet` to initialize it. You can also add a public method for that in class `Pet`.

Comment: try to make description a property instead of a field or try to initialize it in the constructor of Ant

Comment: Is it possible to do the operand only in main method, cause I was not allow to change the class pet or class ant code.

Comment: Fields are implementation details. They aren't properties, not meant to be visible from the outside. Only properties are part of the type's API/interface.

Comment: @Jr.dective change that. What you did is a major bug. *All* libraries expect to find and work with properties, not fields. Serializers (eg XML, JSON, protobuf serializers) work with properties, not the private, changing implementation of fields. Data binding works with properties. Sure, you can work with fields with some extra work, which will have to be repeated every time you use another library or UI element

Comment: But it still doesn't work if I change to ```protected string description { get; set; }```

Comment: If a field is `protected` it cannot be written outside the class or its derived classes... this is a pillar of object oriented programming. So there's no way to make the line `ant.description="small";` to compile. Only way is to create a dedicated constructor which takes a string to initialize `description` : `public Ant(string desc) { description = desc; }`

Comment: What does `protected` mean? It means it's only visible to derived types. `Program` isn't derived from `Ant` or `Pet`. If you want other types to be able to access that property, make it `public`. Otherwise you'll have to set it from *inside* `Pet` or `Ant`. You can have a property whose setter is private or protected if you want, so other types can read it but not set it